# Android Studio cannot copy lots of drawable images to another kotlin project

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

When I select many images + image directories in Android Studio I can COPY this.
Then I view another project (Window->Project B) and want to PASTE the pictures. But this is not working.

How to proceed?

I am using Android Studio 4.2.1, my project is in Kotlin. I want to transfer all classes and images to another project, since MQTT doesn't work properly in one project but works perfect in the other project. Copying files to the other project should be simple...

Additional: Is it possible to change back to Eclipse maybe? Android Studio is taking a huge learning curve..

Comment: Why don't you just copy the files in a file explorer?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did in the end. Also renaming directories is easier that way, Android-Studio will recognize... still this is a fundamental problem for Android-Studio.

Comment: Well you could always report this to the Android Studio or the JetBrains team as a feature request. (JetBrains is probably more relevant).